# textbox: is data bound only when visible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with an invisible TextBox control that is data-bound on a click event. Another click event sets the visibilty to true, but the TextBox is then empty. I could rebind the gridview but don't understand why the TextBox loses it's value. Is this standard behavior?

```
<asp:templatefield HeaderText="NewRate" Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TXBX_NewRate" runat="server" Text = '<%# Bind("NewRate") %>' width="20px" />
        <asp:Label ID="LabelRequirement" runat="server" Text = '<%# Bind("Requirement") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
```

and the event methode:

```
    protected void CheckedChanged_EditarPlazo(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CKBX_NuevoPlazo.Checked == true)
        {
            GridView_ContractFileContent.Columns[11].Visible = true;
```

Comment: The `CheckedChanged_EditarPlazo` method runs on the server, so the page is re-rendered, and that data is lost.

Comment: But then I would expect the gridview to be fully empty. The grid's labels are all dispayed correctly, so that data is not lost

Comment: Have you double checked that the data is bound as expected without `Visible="false"`?

Comment: Yes I did. Once set visible to true, the data is bound and displayed. The data is then lost when clicking the LinkButton that toggles the visibility. Seems to be affected by the postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css class to invisible a column in GridView instead of GridView_ContractFileContent.Columns[11].Visible = false; as this loses value in postback.

In aspx

```html
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hideGridColumn {
            display: none;
        }

        .showGridColumn {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

In code behind file

```
  if (CKBX_NuevoPlazo.Checked == true)
            {
                GridView_ContractFileContent.Columns[1].HeaderStyle.CssClass = "showGridColumn";
                GridView_ContractFileContent.Columns[1].ItemStyle.CssClass = "showGridColumn";
            }
            else
            {
                GridView_ContractFileContent.Columns[1].HeaderStyle.CssClass = "hideGridColumn";
                GridView_ContractFileContent.Columns[1].ItemStyle.CssClass = "hideGridColumn";
            }
```

Comment: Great Idea to do this with CSS! That solved my problem. Thank you!